# Pre and post guideline intervention - statistical analysis

Tags: t-test

I have carried out a study assessing the accuracy of contouring the prostate (i.e. drawing around the prostate gland) pre and post guideline intervention.

16 observers were asked to contour the prostate on three MRI scans (MRI1, MRI2 and MRI3). A STAPLE (ground truth contour) was creating using a contouring software for each MRI scans using the contours. Each contour drawn was compared to the STAPLE and variety of interobserver variability metrics (DICE, average surface distance) were provided.

Guidelines were then provided to the same 16 observers. I asked them to contour the prostate gland on two new MRI scans (MRI4 and MRI5) and duplicated one MRI scan that was used in part one of the study (MRI3) on three MRI scans.

I now have the following data for each scan
Volumes of each contour from the 16 observers
DICE scores for each contour
Average surface distance

I would like to see whether interobserver variability has improved.

I could do a t test of the DICE scores pre and post guideline intervention. Should I do a paired t test for the MRI 3 values and an independent t test for the other two scans?

Alternatively, a kappa statistic for interrater agreement is something I've seen in other similar studies. Could I do the kappa statistic for each scan (for eg. for volumes). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to be able to compare their drawings to a truth, so you need the "correct" contour of the prostate in the images, then you can compare how "close" they were to the contour pre- and post- treatment. Do you have such information?

Comment: thank you for your response, I do - for each MR scan a 'staple' (this is considered the true contour) is created by the planning system and each participant's contour is compared to the staple for each scan. A DICE score / mean surface distance is calculated in comparision to that. It's these results which I would like to compare.

Comment: DICE is used for discrete data so I am not sure how you computed this. Also not sure what "mean surface distance" is or how it was calculated.